# How to mitigate harm caused by unfounded allegations?

Tags: ethics

Someone spread nefarious but completely unfounded ethical allegations against me. That person said he/she was told that I forced a student to plagiarize his/her paper whereas I was the one who strongly advocated for accepting the paper. The paper eventually was rejected because of the oppositions of other reviewers.

The allegations have been heard by many senior people in my field, and have already caused a lot of damage to me, e.g. an honor (given once a year and is highly visible) being retracted, people avoiding me in professional meetings, and who knows what comes next. The person who spread the disinformation is a big shot, is not willing to engage in conversations with me, and is in the so called "leadership" position that can make a lot of decisions. I am very junior and feel powerless.

What should I do?

Comment: The post is still quite unclear.  You were a referee?  For the student's paper or the senior person's?  Are there 2 papers that look similar?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to assume that the allegations are completely baseless as you state. If not - I suggest reaching out to the student as a first step to get their version of events, and potentially apologize/take steps to amend the situation. I am gently suggesting looking into the other side because it seems unlikely that a senior person will go spreading unfounded rumors for the fun of it.

Do you have senior folks on your side? Former advisor, mentor? Talk to them and have them intercede on your behalf.

If this has serious repercussions for you, I suggest that you also contact professional organizations that you both belong to (in computer science I’d think of the ACM or IEEE), they have harassment policies that this falls under. You can also reach out to your department head, since this has serious reputational implications for your department as well.

Good luck, this is an unfortunate situation.

Comment: "it seems unlikely" - likely even bigger people are known to have lost marbles in the past. It's not wrong to suggest OP does some internal analysis what may have gone wrong, and the description of the case is a bit vague to venture a guess what happened, but a priori, unbelievably bad stuff can happen if people think they are above scrutiny. Not much more help possible without more detail, but that may make OP identifiable. In the worst case, they might consider the legal route. If the academic name is already tainted...

Comment: "it seems unlikely that a senior person will go spreading unfounded rumors for the fun of it." When people believe they are defending a victim against mistreatment, often rational thought goes out of the window pretty quick, since any kind of counterargument or skepticism or even listening to what the other side has to say is seen as siding with a bully.

Comment: I myself was certainly stunned at how this senior person at that status would go out of their way to damage my career. And this is the unfortunately thing: this person is at the very top of my professional society, and is friends with many others in the society, so even if I file a complaint through them, I am not sure if it will ever go anywhere.

Comment: Then I reiterate my suggestion- reach out to your department

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I recommend you do is to document all the problems at issue.  Obtain relevant statements and documentation showing your dealings with this other student, including any evidence that would show that the allegations against you are false.  Obtain relevant statements and documentation of any instance where you know or suspect that false information has been spread about you, and document the negative impact on yourself.  Talk to the people in your field that have heard the allegations and ask them if they can confirm the source of those allegations.  Document, document, document.

There are multiple avenues you could consider pursuing to take action in this matter.  One option would be to make an internal complaint within your university.  Another option would be to make an external complaint to a relevant workplace tribunal.  Another option would be to sue the university and/or professor for defamation.  These options could be used separately or together.  For the latter two actions, you should hire a lawyer to advise you and to review the evidence for your complaint.  If you are lodging an internal complaint at the university then you can expect the university to investigate the matter, but if you are making an external complaint then you will need to rely on your own investigation and evidence.

Since this issue appears to be causing you significant career damage, this is probably a situation where it would be worth spending some money to go and see an employment lawyer to get expert advice.  An employment lawyer will be able to tell you the relevant law in your jurisdiction, tell you all your options for different types of actions, tell you the rules that apply to each, and reivew your evidence to see if it is strong enough to warrant actions of different kinds.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The issue is that it's hard to obtain definitive and conclusive evident. I spoke with people who have directly heard the false allegations, but they wouldn't tell me where the source was.

Comment: If you were to make an internal complaint then the university would be expected to investigate the facts of the complaint.  Typically this would mean speaking to those employees who have heard the allegations at issue, and they would be expected to respond candidly and completely to the ethics officers.  Thus, even if they won't talk to you, they probably would not stonewall an investigtaion within the university.